# Pivot scale in cosmology and CMB

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

What is a pivot scale, pivot frequency in general, and particularly in the cosmology? I don't get the idea.

Almost everywhere I found the same the same sentence "we take the standard value of a pivot scale $k=0.05$ Mpc$^{−1}$ (unit of wavenumber) for Planck and pivot frequency as $fcmb=(c/2π)k$". What does it mean?

For example in https://www.cosmos.esa.int/documents/387566/387653/Planck_2018_results_L10.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power spectrum of primordial density perturbations is often modeled as a power law, $$P(k) = A \left(\frac{k}{k_0}\right)^{n-1}.$$ This is the form predicted by slow roll inflation and it fits current CMB and large scale structure data well.  Here, $k_0$ is the *pivot scale*.  It is the wavenumber (scale) were the amplitude, $A$, is measured.

It is possible to include so-called "running", in which the spectral index, $n$, itself has a $k$-dependence, $\alpha = dn/d\ln k$, so that $$\ln P(k) = \ln A+(n(k_0)-1)\ln\left(\frac{k}{k_0}\right)+ \frac{1}{2}\alpha\ln\left(\frac{k}{k_0}\right)^2.$$ Here $k_0$ serves as the scale on which the spectral index is measured.

The choice of pivot scale is not arbitrary in models with running, as certain scales minimize the correlation between $n$ and $\alpha$ (see https://inspirehep.net/literature/744039) which generally reduces errors.

EDIT: For the case of power-law spectra, it is easy to understand why this is called a pivot scale, since the spectra rotate about this amplitude as one varies the spectral index,

[image]

Comment: So, $k_{0}$ is the smallest displacement on the scale, the smallest part of a ruler? Why it is called "pivot scale", not "linear" etc? I don't get it

Comment: I wouldn't get hung up on the etymology.  For a power-law spectrum with $n<1$, wavenumbers with $k < k_0$ (larger length scales) have more power than $k_0$, and those with $k > k_0$ have less power, and conversely for spectra with $n>1$.  I'm not sure I follow why one would call it a "linear" scale.   It's needed so that $P(k) = A$ at some fiducial scale.

Comment: I was just asked by prof. why it is pivot scale, not any different and I really don't get the point why it is. I only gave an example of any different possible scales, such as log or linear and for some reason this one is pivot and don't understand what does it mean and why we particularly here use it.

Comment: @Mateusz I've added a figure to help illustrate the terminology.  I think the last sentence of my previous comment, that it's needed so that $P(k) = A$ at some scale, is the gist of it.  What about that statement confuses you?  How else would you write an expression for the power spectrum that agreed with a measured value for the amplitude on the scale on which it was measured?

Comment: Ok, this figure explain everything for me. I could not catch why they call it pivot, statement "pivot" confuse me a lot more than it should, but graphical answer shows clearly why they call it that way. Thx a lot :). But one more comment, assuming a figure is in log scale a negative/decreasing slope should be for $n<0$ not  $n<1$, doesn't it? But, even if they have both a positive power index they intersect in $k_{0}$, like you said.